# If $T_1, T_2$ are one-to-one linear transformations, prove that $W$ is not one to one

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T_1, T_2$ are one-to-one linear transformations, prove that $W = T_1 + T_2$ is not one-to-one.

I've been working on this for a good hour, but I just can't figure it out.  Here's what I've done so far: (attempted proof by contradiction)

Assume $W$ is one-to-one

$$W(x) = T_1(x) + T_2(x) = 0 \implies x=0$$
$$T_1(x) = T_2(-x)$$

since $T_1,T_2$ are one to one, all I know is that $x=0$ and $-x=0$ which still doesn't help me.

As you can see, I really don't have anything. How is this proved?

Comment: The statement is incorrect.  Where is the problem from?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo/freudian slip on the question, and I just corrected it.  It's a problem from my linear algebra book, written by Jeffrey Holt.

Comment: Thank you.  Are you sure the problem in the book is telling you to prove this incorrect statement?

Comment: I may have made a judgement error, the question exactly reads: "Determine if the statement is true or false, and justify your answer: If $T_1(x)$ and $T_2(x)$ are one-to-one linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, then so is $W(x)=T_1(x)+T_2(x)$  The answer is that the statement is false.

Comment: $I+I$ is 1-1. $I+(-I)$ is not 1-1.

Comment: @Jason: The negation of a "for all" statement is a "there exists" statement.  If it is not always true, that doesn't mean it is always not true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. You can't prove that $W$ isn't one-to-one. (For example, take $T_1 = T_2 = I$.)  You can prove that $W$ isn't *necessarily* one-to-one by exhibiting two one-to-one mappings $T_1$ and $T_2$ for which $T_1 + T_2$  isn't one-to-one.